# How to write a rails query which includes and filter by a 3rd model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the following models:

```
User (id)
  has_many :groups
  has_many :communities

Groups (community_id (OPTIONAL) )
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :community

Communities (id, archived (boolean) )
  has_many :groups
  has_many :group_members, :include => :user
```

I can easily get a user's groups by doing:

current_user.groups

The problem is if a community is archived, I don't want that returned in the current_user.groups.

How can I get all of a user's groups where the community is not archived?

Thanks

Comment: How do you signal that the community is archived?

Comment: Please post that method. What changes in the database to reflect archival.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_user.groups.joins(:community).where('communities.archived' => false)`

Comment: FYI, turns out this does not work as it does not return groups which do not have a community_id, meaning GROUP (community_id) is nil. Those should be returned in the query above. Ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. The reason for that is `joins` by default translates to  SQL `INNER JOIN`. To get it to return groups without a community id, you'll need something that translates to an 'OUTER JOIN'. Unfortunately, as far as I know there's currently no way to do this in a database-independent way in rails. You'd have to pass joins a SQL query like `'OUTER JOIN communities ON groups.community_id = community.id'`. You'll have to modify the exact query depending your choice of database.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit clunky, but you can easily loop through  `current_user.groups`, and check if each group's community has been archived. Maybe something like this

```
all_groups = current_user.groups
final_list = []
all_groups.each { |g| 
  if !g.community.archived
    final_list << g
  end
}
```

That will go through all of the `current_user`'s groups and check each one if they're archived. If not, it adds it to an array called `final_list`. There might be more elegant ways of doing it but that at least gives you the idea of what you should be doing.

Comment: Thanks but that's a pretty heavy solution. SQL only is the goal